# What is the point of deleted destructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I come across the rule (section `N3797::12.8/11 [class.copy]`)

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public
>   member of its class. A defaulted copy/ move constructor for a class X
>   is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> [...]
>
> — any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member of a type
>   with a destructor that *is* deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted
>   constructor, or
>
> [...]

But I can't get the point of deleted destructor appearing in a virtual or direct base class at all. Consider the following simple example:

```
struct A
{
    ~A() = delete;
    A(){ }
};

struct B : A
{
    B(){ }; //error: use of deleted function 'A::~A()'
};

B b; 

int main() { }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/435b3c3df8fce16e)**

It's perfectly unclear to me. I defined 0-argument constructor explcitly and it doesn't use base class destructor. But compiler thinks otherwise. It won't work even if we define `B`'s destructor explicitly:

```
struct A
{
    ~A() = delete;
    A(){ }
};

struct B : A
{
    B(){ };
    ~B(){ };
};

//B b;

int main() {
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/065d960785b5b8dd)**

Couldn't you clarify that thing?

Comment: Related: [How does =delete on destructor prevents allocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847739/how-does-delete-on-destructor-prevents-allocation)

Comment: @RaphaelM. Yes, variables with static storage duration will be destroyed after returning from main function. It's clear. So what's the point of such destructors?

Comment: @Nawaz But in my second example I don't ever allocate a variable.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You don't allocate, what about not deriving A in B. You end up with just A, which can't be used in static allocations, something that may be viewed as a feature. Also, not being able to derive can be viewed as a feature, but for that there's `final` now.

Comment: @pepper_chico Couldn't you provide a reference preventing that allocation?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/b35134df97e00a135449/

Comment: @pepper_chico I can't understand what's that got to do with my question. I haven't decalred a variable in the second example, just    declared A as a superclass for B.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv it ilustrates what I've said, I can enforce the class not have instances being created, while allowing its static member functions to be used. That's just one point for making it useful.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You may try to be more precise on what you're asking, I'm still unsure whether you're looking for a defect in the compiler not following wording of the standard somehow regarding deleted-destructors, or whether you want to know whether they have any point or usability.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv ah, now I got what you're looking for. Well, I dunno all the wording standard, but through your wording, to me at last the explicit constructor of a derived class should be fine to have... since it doesn't needs A's destructor, only B's destructor would need ther other one, afaik.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv What about: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/0d95491c1500023866ab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale for that bullet is covered in [defect report 1191: Deleted subobject destructors and implicitly-defined constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3834.html#1191) which says:

> Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>    A();
>    ~A() = delete;
> };
>
> struct B: A { };
> B* b = new B;
> ```
>
> Under the current rules, B() is not deleted, but is ill-formed because
>   it calls the deleted ~A::A() if it exits via an exception after the
>   completion of the construction of A. A deleted subobject destructor
>   should be added to the list of reasons for implicit deletion in 12.1
>   [class.ctor] and 12.8 [class.copy].

and the proposed resolution was to add the bullet you note above and the same wording to the following section `12.1` [class.ctor] paragraph 5:

> any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member has a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor.

Comment: Let me ask do you use deleted destructor by yourself?

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thank you for the reference to the issue, was very helpful.