# Why am I permitted to declare an object with a deleted destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the following text:

> `[C++11: 12.4/11]:` Destructors are invoked implicitly
>
> - for constructed objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) at program termination (3.6.3),
> - for constructed objects with thread storage duration (3.7.2) at thread exit,
> - for constructed objects with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) when the block in which an object is created exits (6.7),
> - for constructed temporary objects when the lifetime of a temporary object ends (12.2),
> - for constructed objects allocated by a *new-expression* (5.3.4), through use of a *delete-expression* (5.3.5),
> - in several situations due to the handling of exceptions (15.3).
>
> **A program is ill-formed if an object of class type or array thereof is declared and the destructor for the class is not accessible at the point of the declaration.** Destructors can also be invoked explicitly.

Then why does this program compile successfully?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    A(){ };
    ~A() = delete;
};

A* a = new A;

int main() {}

// g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Is GCC just being permissive?

---

I'm inclined to say so, since it rejects the following yet [the standard appears to have no particular rule specific to deleted destructors in an inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26994351/560648) (the only loosely relevant wording is pertinent to the generation of defaulted default constructors):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    A() {};
    ~A() = delete;
};

struct B : A {};

B *b = new B; // error: use of deleted function

int main() {}
```

Comment: No time for standard diving, but "accessible" is not the same as "not-deleted". It's public.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think I've fallen into this trap before.

Comment: That said, GCC still allows it even if made private.

Comment: Shouldn't `struct B : A {};` be `struct B : public A {};`?

Comment: @David: The two are strictly equivalent.

Comment: But there is no object construction, only pointer construction and no delete call. Why you think, that compiler should no compile it?

Comment: @ForEveR: Because (a) I quoted the standard text that states so (or appeared to before I realised I'd misread it), and (b) it rejects the same in an inheritance hierarchy, as I point out in the question.

Comment: In the latest version of the standard N4140, the last phrase is slightly modified: "A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the invocation." So the "potentially" comes in, which make things more unclear. Should the object be instantiated? It cannot be, as we saw before.

Comment: @vsoftco: That wording is so much better.

Comment: Yeah, it is better, but still not perfect. Is your question the follow up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986570/why-does-destructor-call-if-its-deleted-and-doesnt-call-if-its-not ? That one is also a bit of a mystery.

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes and I linked to that in my question.

Comment: Your code doesn't declare an object or array of type `A`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, I suppose it doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, I missed the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847739/how-does-delete-on-destructor-prevents-allocation

Comment: @sajas: I don't see the relevance.

Comment: **This question is a bit of a mess of misconceptions; ironic since I've corrected them myself in past self-answered questions. Think I'll drop this one and focus on the original question. Thanks folks!**

Comment: Related to [What is the point of deleted destructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26942887/1708801)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first part is not ill-formed because the standard text doesn't apply - no object of type A is declared there.

For the second part, let's review how object construction works. The standard says (15.2/2) that if any part of construction throws, all fully constructed subobjects up to that point are destroyed in reverse order of construction.

This means that the code underlying a constructor, if all written out by hand, would look something like this:

```
// Given:
struct C : A, B {
   D d;
   C() : A(), B(), d() { /* more code */ }
};

// This is the expanded constructor:
C() {
  A();
  try {
    B();
    try {
      d.D();
      try {
        /* more code */
      } catch(...) { d.~D(); throw; }
    } catch(...) { ~B(); throw; }
  } catch(...) { ~A(); throw; }
}
```

For your simpler class, the expanded code for the default constructor (whose definition is required by the `new` expression) would look like this:

```
B::B() {
  A();
  try {
    // nothing to do here
  } catch(...) {
    ~A(); // error: ~A() is deleted.
    throw;
  }
}
```

Making this work for cases where no exception can possibly be thrown after initialization for some subobject has been completed is just too complex to specify. Therefore, this doesn't actually happen, because the default constructor for B is implicitly defined as deleted in the first place, due to the last bullet point in N3797 12.1/4:

> A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
>
> - [...]
> - any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member has a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor.

The equivalent language exists for copy/move constructors as the fourth bullet in 12.8/11.

There is also an important paragraph in 12.6.2/10:

> In a non-delegating constructor, the destructor for each direct or virtual base class and for each non-static data member of class type is potentially invoked.

Comment: Ooh, the exceptions are a good point. 12.6.2/10 appears to be what we're looking for in [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26986570/560648), but it's not present in C++11, only C++14.

Comment: Wouldn't it be right to consider destructors mentioned in 12.6.2/10 potentially invoked only if the constructor is not `noexcept`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The paragraph is indeed new to C++14, but since it was introduced by a defect report (DR1424, to be precise), it still applies to C++11, or at least that is generally the opinion of the compiler writers. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1424

Comment: @AntonSavin Quite possibly. See DR1915, which asks exactly for that, but was declared a language extension, so the discussion is moved to the EWG. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1915

Answer (score 3):

It's that `B`'s destructor is generated by the compiler at the line of your error and it has a call to `A`'s destructor which is deleted, hence the error.  In the first example nothing is trying to call `A`'s destructor hence no error.

Comment: Why does `B()` "have a call to `A`'s destructor"? I find nothing in the standard that suggests this, and it's counter-intuitive to boot.

Comment: It's ~B() that has a call to (it's base class's destructor) ~A()

Comment: Yet, `~B()` is never invoked. So by your own logic that should not matter.

Comment: I think it is so because the compiler cannot even generate a default destructor for `B`, as the default destructor must be able to destruct `A` (hence must be able to call `A::~A()`.

Comment: The compiler cannot know if ~B() is or isn't ever called (halting problem) so it generates one at your error line (unless you tell not to with `delete`).

Comment: Not true. Nobody asks the compiler to determine whether the destructor is called in any dynamic execution (which reduces to the halting problem). The only question is if the destructor is ever mentioned at all, which is trivial to determine for the compiler. The code in the second example never references B's destructor.

Comment: @SebastianRedl But the code in the 2nd example *contains* B's destructor. Only linker will know if the destructor actually gets called or not, so compiler does not have the option of not creating it (unless explicitly told to do so by using `=delete`).

Comment: @hyde The code doesn't contain B's destructor. It contains the class definition, from which the compiler can generate the destructor on demand. But any file that can demand the destructor must have the class definition available anyway (that's why class definitions are usually in headers), so the compiler never needs to create a destructor in any translation unit "just in case" another TU needs it. Any TU that needs the destructor will cause it to be generated, and the linker will deduplicate if it is generated more than once.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this is what happens.

The implicitly generated `B()` constructor will first of all construct its base class subobject of type `A`. The language then states that if an exception is thrown during execution of the body of the `B()` constructor, the `A` subobject must be destroyed. Hence the need to access the deleted `~A()` - it is formally needed for when the constructor throws. Of course, since the generated body of `B()` is empty this can never ever happen, but the requirement that `~A()` should be accessible is still there.

Of course, this is 1) just a guess from my side of why there is an error in the first place and 2) not in any way a quote of the standardese to say whether this would actually be formally ill-formed or just an implementation detail in gcc. Could perhaps give you a clue of where in the standard to look though...

Answer (score 1):

[Accessibility is orthogonal to deletedness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20816214/560648):

> `[C++11: 11.2/1]:` If a class is declared to be a base class (Clause 10) for another class using the `public` access specifier, the `public` members of the base class are accessible as `public` members of the derived class and `protected` members of the base class are accessible as `protected` members of the derived class. If a class is declared to be a base class for another class using the `protected` access specifier, the `public` and `protected` members of the base class are accessible as `protected` members of the derived class. If a class is declared to be a base class for another class using the `private` access specifier, the `public` and `protected` members of the base class are accessible as `private` members of the derived class.

There is this:

> `[C++11: 8.4.3/2]:` A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed. *[ Note:* This includes calling the function implicitly or explicitly and forming a pointer or pointer-to-member to the function. It applies even for references in expressions that are not potentially-evaluated. If a function is overloaded, it is referenced only if the function is selected by overload resolution. *—end note ]*

But you never "refer to" the deleted destructor.

(I still can't explain why the inheritance example doesn't compile.)