# Can I omit the type arguments of smart pointers in my header files?

Tags: c++, package, header-files

I am building a C++ library. I have a `struct` that contains a `std::unique_ptr` to another `struct` that I would like to hide from the user.

For example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyPrivateStruct> y;
};
```

Now, I need to specify `MyStruct` in a header file that the user can include so that they know its layout. However, this requires that I also expose the header for `MyPrivateStruct`, which I do not want to do. Since the size of a `unique_ptr` is the same regardless of the type, is it possible to do something like this?

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<auto> y;
};
```

The type of the `y` would then be determined by my `cpp` files.

---

This is not *quite* the same question as [Can't use std::unique_ptr<T> with T being a forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386185/cant-use-stdunique-ptrt-with-t-being-a-forward-declaration) since the answer to this question is to use a forward declaration. That question is about a problem when using forward declarations.

Comment: Just forward declare the struct? Or is that what you are trying to avoid doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use std::unique\_ptr<T> with T being a forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386185/cant-use-stdunique-ptrt-with-t-being-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: @LogicStuff not quite; see edit.

Comment: You don't need to expose the header for `MyPrivateStruct`. You need to forward declare it, which is one line: `struct MyPrivateStruct;` The client doesn't need to know anything about its definition in its header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!

```
struct MyPrivateStruct;

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyPrivateStruct> y;
};
```

Comment: Although for me in Visual Studio it seems I have to create an empty destructor in MyStruct and define it in the cpp file instead of using the default to get it to compile because of the incomplete type. Like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9954553/487892

Comment: @drescherjm Yes you do. `~unique_ptr` will call the destructor of whatever its templated type is. If you allow the default destructor to be generated, it can't see the definition of `~MyPrivateStruct` because it is only forward declared at that point.

Comment: Yeah, part of the pain.  If you use shared_ptr instead you don't have that problem, but I wouldn't recommend using it just because of that.

Answer (score 2):

`MyPrivateStruct` in `std::unique_ptr<MyPrivateStruct> y;` does not have to be a *complete type*.

That is, you can forward declare it by writing

`struct MyPrivateStruct;`

prior to the declaration of `y`.

Comment: Wrong. C++ standard does not insist on it. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_GCC_does_not_warn_for_mismatch_between_struct_and_class_.28-Wmismatched-tags.29_.3F

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that. Perhaps I shouldn't base my knowledge solely on my Microsoft toolchain. Thank you so much,

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy VC++ doesn't comply with the standard on a [number of fronts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78(v=vs.140).aspx)