# std::unique_ptr of an incomplete pimpl type surprisingly compiles fine when its host class is used polymorphically

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom, incomplete-type

I have a class `foo` that derives from `base`, and hence have a virtual destructor. Class `foo` implements the pimpl idiom with a `std::unique_ptr` of the incomplete type `foo::impl`.
Like you can see in the code below, it doesn't compile as expected if I try to delete a `foo` instance because `std::unique_ptr` needs to know `foo::impl`. On the other hand, it **does** compile when I delete it through its base class. I don't understand why it does so and more importantly I would like to know if it is undefined behavior.

```cpp
// Header.h
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() =default;
};

class foo: public Base
{
public:
  foo();

private:
  class impl;
  std::unique_ptr<impl> p_;
};
```

```cpp
// Source.cpp
#include "Header.h"

class foo::impl
{
};

foo::foo():p_(std::make_unique<foo::impl>()) {};
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Base> t = std::make_unique<foo>(); // this one compiles and links and I would have expected it not to.

  //foo b; // this one does not compile as expected
  return 1;
}
```

I have the same results with Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: After this declaration  std::unique_ptr<Base> t = std::make_unique<foo>(); the internal value of t is nullptr.

Comment: This looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58506694) I asked recently. I believe it is a bug in `msvc`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why? This [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Whzh1rNgjL7tj5Uw) shows something else.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  make_unique construct an object. it's a wrapper for `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica I was mistaken.

Comment: @Mark, I agree it is similar. When posting this question, I did not realize the pimpl approach actually had nothing to do with the problem. I guess I should close this issue and mark it a duplicate of your question, but I don't know how to do this.